# How to extract only phone numbers from div with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that contains texts and phone numbers

```html
<div>
    <span>+1 704 849 3340</span>
    <span>+5 662-325-5582</span>
    <span>+8 804-896-4087</span>
    <span>+545 804-896-4087</span>
    <span>5854</span>
    <span>text</span>
</div>
```

How can I access the phone numbers in javascript, that start with a +?

Comment: It would be easier to extract them all and then filter out ones without a `+`.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: you can use `getElementsByTagName()` to get tags, then use `innerHTML` to extract values. once you have done that you can use some "post processing" to reformat numbers and stuff.

Comment: You write that you have a div but in the code you posted there is no div.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you desire the code to do?

```js
const tags = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
const filteredTags = [];


for(let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){

  if(tags[i].innerHTML[0] == '+')
    filteredTags.push(tags[i].innerHTML);
}

console.log(filteredTags);
```

```html
<body>
<span>+1 704 849 3340</span>
<span>+5 662-325-5582</span>
<span>+8 804-896-4087</span>
<span>+545 804-896-4087</span>
<span>5854</span>
<span>text</span>
</body>
```